# Interior consists of both limit points and isolated points.

Tags: general-topology

X: topl space

A: subset of X

In standard topology of R, interior of A looks like consists only of limit points.

In discrete topology, interior of A looks like consists only of isolated points.

Is there any example of interior consists of both limit points and isolated points?

Comment: $X = (-\infty, -1) \cup \mathbb{N},\; A = (-3,-2) \cup \{4,5,6\}$

Comment: In that case, intA = (-3,-2) and all of this points are limit points.

Comment: No, the nonnegative integers are isolated points of $X$, and so $\operatorname{int} A = (-3,-2) \cup \{4,5,6\} = A$ consists of isolated points [$4,5,6$] and limit points [$(-3,-2)$].

Comment: What is the topology on X?

Comment: The subspace topology induced by $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I got it. You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you let $\tau = \mathcal{P}(X)$ be the discrete topology, then every set is clopen, so $A^\circ = A$.

Comment: Sure. So what ?

Comment: @Evzone so it consists of both limit points (there isn't any in discrete topology) and isolated points.

Comment: What are you saying? Why it consists of both limit points and isolated points?

Comment: @Evzone All isolated points of $A$ are elements of $A$. Also, $A$ has no limit points since $\tau$ is discrete.

Comment: Sure. So what ? Then Why it consists of both limit points and isolated points?

Comment: @Evzone There are no limit points, so all limit points are contained in $A^\circ$. This is a vacuous truth. All isolated points are contained in $A^\circ$ since $A$ is open.

Comment: @Evzone This gives a valid example for your criterion.

Comment: I don't think so. I want something meaningful answer, not like "play on words" using vacuous truth.

Comment: @Evzone Using vacuous truth is perfectly valid in mathematics. It is used to establish the openness of $\emptyset$ in some definitions.

Comment: Ok. But I don't want it now in my question.

Comment: Why my comment has been deleted? who deleted it?

Comment: Henry, did you delete my comment?

Comment: @Evzone I'm not a mod. I can't delete comments.